# Gaussian Distribution for Latitude/Longitude Coordinates

Tags: normal-distribution, spatial

I have a bunch of latitude/longitude coordinates and if I plot it on a map, it seems to follow a bivariate distribution. I would like to estimate the distribution of points using a bivariate distribution. However, I am afraid that using a bivariate distribution directly would not work since the distance between points on the latitude and longitude coordinates is determined by Haversine distance, not L2 distance. Thus it can lead to skewed results to compute the mean of the points. I was wondering if there is distribution that is related to a bivariate distribution for latitude and longitude coordinates or is it possible to map the latitude and longitude coordinates onto a plane (not a 3D-surface).

Comment: A bivariate Gaussian distribution ranges over $(-\infty,\infty)\times (-\infty,\infty)$ but a sphere is finite. There are bivariate distributions on the sphere that may be suitable, or you may even want to look at some form of kernel density estimate. You might possibly find Fisher et al. *Statistical Analysis of Spherical Data* (1993) of some help. [amazon](http://www.amazon.com/Statistical-Analysis-Spherical-Data-Fisher/dp/0521456991) or [book webpage](http://www.cambridge.org/au/academic/subjects/astronomy/astronomy-general/statistical-analysis-spherical-data) (see the ToC, especially ch 4)

Comment: (ctd) ... See [the (von Mises-)Fisher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mises%E2%80%93Fisher_distribution), and [Kent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kent_distribution) distributions for example. These could perhaps then be transformed to latitude/longitude (though I wouldn't like to do the algebra, it should be reasonably straightforward to do numerically).

Comment: +1 For a recent example of how bivariate density estimates can go horribly wrong when one does not pay attention to the spherical geometry, see the illustration in the question at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152094.  *Of course* it's possible to map the coordinates onto a plane (for otherwise world atlases could not exist), but the problem lies in choosing an appropriate projection for the map.  No projection will preserve the spherical metric (but some can preserve it to a good approximation across small regions). But what does any of this have to do with "Gaussian" distributions?

Comment: You're right, a bivariate distribution wouldn't would properly for latitude/longitude coordinates. Perhaps you could first convert your latitude/longitude coordinates to ECEF.

Comment: What are the ranges of your lat/long data? If the range is very narrow, then mapping them to a plane then working with x-y may actually work. Also, this is not a geometry question. Consider this if your data is of the bicylists then chances are they're riding on the roads, so their paths are constrained. Or if you're mapping flight patterns of birds they might be synced to the movement of sun or moon or something that like that would bring certain symmetries that you need to account for in your distribution

Comment: @Glen_b By re-expressing (lat,lon) as unit 3D vectors (which is just the transformation from spherical to cartesian coordinates), one can use the von Mises-Fisher or Kent distributions directly.